# how do I save the length of a input as a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to see the amount of characters imputed and save it as a variable!

I have tried multiple things from other websites but none of them work or they are for java

I am new to this website and python so i hope you can help!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `len()` function

`length = len(input("Enter stuff: "))`